# JavaScript setTimeout() won't wait to Execute?

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout, setinterval

Consider the following example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function alertBox(){
        alert('Hello World!');
    }
    function doSomething(){
        setInterval(alertBox(), 5000); //This is for generic purposes only
    };
    function myFunction(){
        setTimeout(doSomething(),3000);
    };

    myFunction();
</script>
```

What is it that causes this to execute ***IMMEDIATELY***, rather than waiting the 3 seconds set, as well as only executing the alert ***ONCE***, rather than at the scheduled 5 second intervals?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Mason

Comment: Well, **the callback is invoked immediately** (and the *result* is passed to `setTimeout`) .. pass the Function-object instead.

Comment: This is probably the single most asked javascript question on SO.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think closured variables in loops might tie it .. ;-)

Comment: Well I certainly feel like a fool - This is what I get for leaving JS alone for so long >.<

Comment: @MasonWinsauer Feel your pain.

Comment: Refer to my comment, it might useful for you.https://stackoverflow.com/a/60630117/4248767

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
alertBox()
```

Doesn't this look like an immediate function call?

Try passing the function (without executing it) instead:

```
setInterval(alertBox, 5000);
```

Answer (score 14):

its because you are executing the function, not passing a function object.

```
function myFunction(){
    setTimeout(doSomething, 3000); // no () on the function
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Following codes executing differently,

```
setTimeout(console.log('Nuwan'),0)---(A); and 
setTimeout(function(){console.log('Nuwan'),0}) --- (B)
```

The reason is when (B) is executing, CallStack in javascript runtime push the setTimeout() to web API and 
WebAPI waits 0 seconds to push the callback function to the event queue and then EventLoop pushes the callback to the stack after the current stack is empty.

In Case (A), console.log() directly calling because it is in the WepAPI, no need to go for an event loop to execute.

**More Ref:** 
WebAPIs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console_API
Javascript Runtime and Event Loop: https://cybrohosting.com/knowledgebase/17/How-JavaScript-works-in-browser-and-node.html