# Using setInterval() function to make pomodoro timer

Tags: javascript

My code is bellow, it doesn't throw errors but it stops after running ones.

I tried reviewing this codes and searching through documentation, but couldn't find anything, possibly due to my level of knowledge.

```
var timeNumbers = ['count','working','resting'];
var amountData  = {'count':0,'working':0,'resting':0};   

function fromCount(){
    if(timeVa['working'] == false) return;
    var amountDataNo1 = Array.from(amountData);
    var dataW = setInterval(loseTimeW(1),1000);

    function loseTimeW(n){
        if(amountDataNo1[timeNumbers[n]] == 0){
            clearInterval(dataW);
            timeVa['resting'] == true;
        }else{
            amountDataNo1[timeNumbers[n]]--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve], not all of your code.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837562/javascript-settimeout-wont-wait-to-execute

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182714/why-does-the-setinterval-callback-execute-only-once

Comment: The first argument of `setInterval()` is the function it must invoke periodically. You don't pass a function to it but `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of `setInterval()` is the function it must invoke periodically.

The first argument you pass to `setInterval()` is the value returned by the call `loseTimeW(1)`. But the `loseTimeW()` function does not `return` anything, consequently the value of `loseTimeW(1)` is `undefined`.

I guess your intention is to invoke `loseTimeW()` with argument `1` every `1000` milliseconds. You can achieve this easily. `setInterval()` accepts two or more arguments. It passes the arguments starting with the third one (if any) to the callback (argument #1) when it invokes it.

The working code is something like:

```
var dataW = setInterval(loseTimeW, 1000, 1);
```

Read more about [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: Alternatively, `setInterval(new Function() { loseTimeW(1); }, 1000);` , or `setInterval(() => loseTimeW(1), 1000);`

Comment: @BenR. [`new Function()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Syntax) does not work this way.